# Web Api 2 with two method with the same HTTP verb an angularjs resources

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api2, ngresource

I have this controller:

```
public class SeguiAttivazioneController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult DoWork1()
    {
        ...            
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult DoWork2()
    {
        ...            
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet] //I would like to have a search with GET verb, but I cannot validate my ModelState with dataAnnotation
    public IHttpActionResult AnotherSearch(string filter1, string filter2, ...)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult DoSearch(SearchFilter filters)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SubmitForm(FormData data)
    {
        ...
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two methods with same HttpVerbs (2 for GET and 2 for POST)... I don't know if I am violating REST principles... If so, I would like to avoid... 
In this moment I am using AngularJs + NgResources to call my Controller..

```
public_area
    .factory("SeguiAttivazioneService", function ($resource) {
        //return {
        //    seguiAttivazione: $resource("/api/SeguiAttivazione/", null,
        //                        {
        //                            'get2': { method: 'GET', url: '/api/SeguiAttivazione/GetActivationStatus2' }
        //                        })
        //};
        return {
            seguiAttivazione: $resource("/api/SeguiAttivazione/")
        };
    });
```

I am trying to do a GET:

```
$scope.getActivationStatus = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($scope.segui_attivazione_form.$valid) {
        var request =
            new SeguiAttivazioneService
                .seguiAttivazione()
                .$get({ }, getActivationStatusSuccess, getActivationStatusError);
    }
};
```

But (correctly) I obtain an "Internal Server Error 500", because I have to GET method. How Can I solve this problem? (I suppose I will have same problem with POST too)

Thank you

**UPDATE**
Here the class of the filters

```
public class SearchFilter 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="")]
    public string CodiceFiscale { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:\d{11,16})|(?:[a-zA-Z]{6}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z])$", ErrorMessage = "Codice Fiscale o Partita IVA non validi")]
    public string CodiceRichiesta { get; set; }
}
```

With this class I can use data Annotation to validate my model... If I do a GET Method I cannot use data annotation validation anymore...

Comment: A REST endpoint should be discriminatory. Take a look at the examples of this wikipedia article (may not be the best source, but the examples are good) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer. A method on an URI should have only one entry point in your backend

Comment: So you mean that I should have just one GET and just one POST?

Comment: For a URI endpoint yes. I'll try to make a short answer about the REST Uri

Comment: Simone, I think I answered your original question. If now you have a different question regarding Validation with Data Annotations, please, don't mix it up in your current question. Create a new question where you now explain what you want to do. This will make it more possible for someone to answer it. I have some ideas in my head, but your question is not clear. Please, explain clearly the new scenery, and make also clear if any of the answers to this post answered your original question or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some explanation about a the REST Endpoints.

In REST we are manipulating ressources. As collections or individual.

Classics endpoint would be :

```
GET /rest/houses DATA : none -> will return a collection of houses

GET /rest/houses/{id} DATA : none -> will return the house find by its {id}

POST /rest/houses DATA : {"street":"3 bdv NY-city"} -> will create a new house object with the given data

PUT /rest/houses/{id} DATA : { "id":"{id}", "street":"4 bvd NY-city"} -> will update the whole house ressource find by its {id}

PATCH /rest/houses/{id} DATA : { "street":"4bvd NY-city" } -> will update the given fields of the house ressource find by its {id}

DELETE /rest/houses/{id} DATA : none -> will delete the house ressource find by its id.
```

There is too much things to know about restfull API that i can't give you all the keys. But try to find some good articles on the subjects such as :

http://www.restapitutorial.com/index.html

Not sure if this answer your question, but i hope it'll help you.

EDIT 1 :

Since i have to add some point about a restfull way to give some complicated action i'll give you the restfull url way to go.

In a restful world (extremely rare) you know only one entry point of your rest API let say this :

```
GET /rest/
```

This uri will respond you will all the services that the api can provide
Exemple :

```
{
 "resources":"/rest/ressources",
 "apiInfo" : "/rest/api/info"
}
```

To get your ressources informations you'll follow the link

```
 GET response.resources
```

I may respond something like :

```
{
 "houses":"/rest/ressources/houses/",
 "cars"  :"/rest/ressources/cars"
}
```

Now we want the houses

```
GET response.houses
```

Response :

```
 {
  "fields":[{
    "constructionYear","street"
   }],
  "search":"/rest/houses"
  "create":"/rest/houses"
 }
```

etc... And at this place you can add some non restful endpoints. In a restful way. This action will be hold by a restful resource. Somes API that are using this kind of great Restful.

Standard Rest API : 
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

Restful API :
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

Comment: Clear.. thank you... At this point, here exactly my problem.. I have a search (POST).. but if my search does not find anything I must create the object.. so I do a create (POST)... I have two POST for same REST service... Honestly I think that the search should be a GET but If I transform my search in GET I canno validate my ModelState with data Annotation... I updated my question

Comment: Why not doing it in two step ? First you do a search with GET, when the GET response come back with no result you fire a POST request to create the resource. I'm not sure i get you're problem with the validate with data Annotation.  Do you want to validate your GET parameters ?

Comment: yes, I need to validate them because they must respect some "pattern": for example the Italian fiscal code (XXXXXX00X00X000X)... I already do a check client-side, but I think it is better if I do it also server side..

Comment: Unfortunately i have no knowledge in asp.net, maybe if you want to follow rest principes you should ask an other question focused on "How to validate GET url parameters through ModelState with data annotation" if you don't mind being restful you could just create an other route like POST /myressource/search and the rest one still the same : POST /myressource/ -> create the ressource.

Answer (score 0):

The question is that the Web API infrastructure must have a way to choose one of the possible methods.

One way is changing the Web API route configuration, including an `/{action}/` segment. If you do so it will work exactly like MVC, and you have to always include the action name.

The other way is making the received parameters different in each method, so that the Web API infrastructure can discover which method you're trying to invoke. You can read this answer I've written today for a similar question: [How can I add multiple Get actions with different input params when working RESTFUL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212903/how-can-i-add-multiple-get-actions-with-different-input-params-when-working-rest/30213596#30213596).

As a final comment in that answer I say that the parameters can be also discerned by using route contraints.

The first solution of having to include the action name in all invocation is not RESTful, but do you need or prefer it to be RESTful for any particular reason?

Comment: No I do not need, I prefer... I think it is just better if I respect the RESP principle.... or not?

Comment: REST principe is just a way to unitize API definition. If you follow this, you'll have a clear and easy distinction of how and what you can do in your API.

Comment: It's not best or worst... id depends on what you want to achieve. Anyway you know have the tools for keeping it RESTful or not. In my opinion the URL aspect is not the most important part of a RESTful API, and, if you've got a lot of business logic in your API it will behard to make a RESTful implementation. If you did something like a data service without none or little businedd object in it, then you could make easily it RESTful (that's ODATA!). So, I wouldn't worry to much about it.

Comment: @Okazari if you read my comment perhaps you'll agree that if you have a lot of business logic in the API instead of making it more clear, you can make it more confusing. If you're simply reading, deleting and modifying data, and little more, it will be very clear. It's my personal opinion, but I'd like to know yours.

Comment: @JotaBe I'm not sure i understood all your explanation (Not enough english skills :( ) but in my opinion for classic data manipulation, simple Restful is a good way to go. If you want to do more complicated things, you'll have two solutions. You can create some not Restful endpoint or choose to be even more restful. In the "real" restful API your ressource will give you a collection of "links" that are corresponding to actions. I'll give more details in my answer about this.

Comment: @JotaBe I edited my post. I think my explanations got confused. But i hope it could help you to understand my point of view.

Comment: @Okazari. Then we agree, if you need more than editing data making a RESTful API is complicating without a reason. Exposing those links to actions related to the exposed collections is hard to do, and I really doubt that it will give benefits to the user of the service. And if you want to expose data there are RESTful solutions implemented out of the box, like ODATA, which are implemente with nearly zero effort.